# unable to unlock advanced settings of bios in haeir y11b laptop

Tags: windows-10, bios, external-hard-drive, multi-boot, dualboot

I have Haier y11b laptop. it has two drives. one drive capacity is 30gb which has windows installed. the other drive capacity is 465gb. as the 30gb drive capacity is too low for other software to be installed in this drive. i somehow installed windows in second drive using wintousb(third party software). but the problem is that the second drive is not appearing in bios settings. I need to unlock advanced settings in bios for that I don't know the exact keys. Please let me know how to unlock its advanced settings. Aptio American Megatrends is installed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try and tap F8 as the computer is starting to access the boot menu, and boot to USB from there. Can you add a screenshot of your Disk Management page? It seems unlikely that your main drive is only 30 GB...

Comment: @Cpt.Whale It is a 32GB "SSD" (an old an slow eMMC is more like it) + a 500GB **HDD**. This is obviously an X-Y problem. The author is clueless and used WintoUSB in an internal drive (!!!) and now is asking how to boot from it? It's beyond belief.

Comment: @MentorGeek You can MANUALLY install Windows in the HDD (worst case scenario you have to have the ESP in the 32GB drive) but even that it's dumb because HDDs are SLOOOOOOWWWW!! Instead replace that 500GB drive with a SATA SSD (very cheap nowadays) and then install Windows. The 32GB drive is likely to be a soldered eMMC so it can't be replaced, just ignore it.

Comment: i have uploaded the pictures. Firstly i installed windows in c drive using bootable usb and i did not find any difficulty doing this. Later i tried to install windows from bootable usb to drive 1 but i could not do it as i was getting this error of not able to install windows in this drive. then i use wintousb software to install windows in drive 1. but now its not appearing in bios. i have tried all available options on internet but could not get the solution. the only solution that i could not tried yet is to go to bios advanced settings and turn on the usb mass storage. plz guide me.

Comment: Nothing else to add. All you're thinking of is ridiculous (and that is being nice). The error is about a partitioning scheme mismatch - Windows in UEFI mode strictly requires GPT and conversely MBR for BIOS/Legacy mode; you want the former therefore you need to make sure the the partitioning scheme a the drive is GPT before trying to install. And again, installing any OS nowadays in a HDD, especially Windows, is stupid AF.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Please don't be so hostile.

Comment: i have spent many days learning to solve low capacity problem. then i came here to ask for help as i could not find any solution over the internet which i find helpful.  I thought knowlegebale people have more patience than others. Alas!
moreover i have tried all before coming here. even converting disks to gpt. 
can anyone plz provide me the solution or keys for entering advanced settings in bios or something else which will be helpful. for now i dont have enough resources to buy anything.

Comment: Knowledgeable people do have patience for proper questions no matter the skill level. People tend to NOT have that much patience for X-Y problems that askers double down in even after having been pointed out the issue and, on top of that, a serious attempt of saving you from yourself happened here. But you think you know better so I'll leave it at that. Maybe when you notice your question NOT being answered - comments aren't answers -, maybe then you'll realize the problems it has.

Comment: i never said that i know more than anyone else. if that was the case i would not been here. i never understood the term you mentioned X-Y problem? please elaborate.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with ChanganAuto's phrasing, per se, but he's correct: you are making assumptions and those assumptions are causing you to think the solution is someplace it isn't.

Your best choice is to replace the HDD with an SSD and use a normal Windows installer (not WinToUSB or whatever you used) to install windows there, and either ignore the smaller drive or figure out something to do with it.

We cannot assume that your BIOS can be "unlocked" given that you've already been given instructions how to do that and they have apparently been ineffective.

Wanting something to be a solution will not make it the solution.